# symbolic links not work with htaccess in xampp

Tags: url-rewriting, xampp, symlink

For several days i'm trying to figure out how symbolic links work with htaccess rewriterule
and for that I've created a new project to help me to apply these rules in one website
for which I work so the context is:
In my xampp folder on local-host I have a main page **index.php** that I want to call "home"
and in this page I have some url links for two pages called **objectives.php** and **news.php** where I wish to load dynamic content in future website

here is my code for **index.php**

```
<p><a href="objectives.php?menu=corporate-objectives">  
Corporate objectives - load page content for this item from objectives table</a></p>  
<p>Functional objectives ...</p>  
<p>Unit objectives ...<p>  
<p><a href="news.php?article=meeting-news">  
Meeting news - load content from news table for meeting</a></p>  
<p>Press release news ...</p>  
<p>Other news ...<p>
```

and here is the code for the other two pages:
**objectives.php**

```
$pages = $_REQUEST['menu'];  
echo "This is Corporate objectives -objectives.php here I load content  
according to this menu item value"."<br>";  
echo "Menu item value: ".$pages;
```

**news.php**

```
$pages = $_REQUEST['article'];  
echo "This is Meeting news - news.php here I load news content  
for this article value from news table "."<br>";  
echo "Article value: ".$pages;
```

What I 've read before is that with RewriteRule in htaccess I can change the url to become symbolic or friendly for example:
**/MyTest_proj/objectives.php?menu=corporate-objectives**
I want to transform in
**/MyTest_proj/corporate-objectives**
and
**/MyTest_proj/news.php?article=meeting-news**
in
**/MyTest_proj/meeting-news**
so for that I have completed in my **.htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ objectives.php?menu=$1  
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ news.php?article=$1
```

The problem is... nothing happens so I've tried to change something for testing
url links from main page:

```
<a href="corporate-objectives"> ...</a>  
<a href="meeting-news">...</a>
```

and it work BUT only for **objectives.php** for wich I have rewrite rule, the second page
it's load in the same page instead of **news.php**
I have tried in many ways to change the rules but nothig work..for several times,
the most common error was like error 401
I apologize for the long content and please, tell me that something can be done after all
thanks !

Comment: I forgot to specify that this mentioned project is for testing

Comment: I've managed to put the right rules (I think) and it worked,  here is the code:  **RewriteRule ^home(.*)$ index.php**  **RewriteRule ^news/([-a-zA]+)/?$ news.php?article=$1**  **RewriteRule ^objectives/([-a-zA-Z]+)/?$ objectives.php?menu=$1**  I suppose it wasn't work before because I've used the same patterns. Also I've changed the href's to display simbolic url's  in address bar  **<a href="objectives/corporate-objectives">**  **<a href="news/meeting-news">**  wich is also worked BUT STILL,  I'm not sure if I did the right thing so please I need advice or ok confirmation  Thanks!